Devise unable to find_for_authentication
Having upgraded Rails from 7.1.4 -> 7.2.1 users can't log in any more. Strangely, this only appears to affect development mode. The problem appears to be caused when the sessions controller calls:
resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

...which will call one of these methods in User.rb:
# Implement the requirement to supply username or email to login.
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions[:login]
  where(['lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value', { value: login.downcase.strip }]).first if login
end

# Authenticate user by means of a JSON Web token.
def self.find_for_jwt_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  where('id = ?', conditions.to_i).first
end

I get the following errors, respectively:
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for "knirirr":String):

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for "123":Integer):

I've been delving through the Devise and Warden gems' code and can't spot anything. There's not anything obvious in config/environments/development.rb either, and I can't reproduce this with a newly-created Rails app.
Can anyone suggest what might be behind this, or where to look?
This is using:

Ruby 3.2.2
Rails 7.2.1
Devise 4.9.4


This problem has vanished after upgrading to the latest version (7.2.2 IIRC); presumably it was in one of the Gems which have also been upgraded.
